# get_surface().blit() vs var_screen.blit()

Tags: performance, pygame, blit

I am wondering - is it more performant to save your pygame "window" surface as a variable, and call blit on the variable for every image or call get_surface().blit(...) every time?

Especially when it comes to games, there are lots and lots of pngs/sprites/something to be displayed. I was wondering whether anyone has experience with the performance of calling the function over saving your "screen" in a variable?

Example one with variable:

```
screen =  pygame.display.get_surface()
while True: 
    screen.blit(my_image.png)
```

Example two:

```
while True:
     pygame.display.get_surface().blit(my_image.png)
```

Best regards, 
Cribber

Comment: test both and show your result. As for me first version should be faster but you will not see difference in game. First version is also more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the advice and run a performance test myself and performance wise it really doesn't matter apparently.

So the deciding factor being readability, I will take the variable option with screen.blit().

```
start_time = time.time()
while i <= 1000:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()

    #pygame.display.get_surface().blit(png, (x, y))
    screen.blit(png, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    i += 1
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
```

1) display.get_surface().blit()

Sum = 14.827981948852539

```
x100 - Elapsed time: 0.31400012969970703
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.9339892864227295
x1000 - Elapsed time:  2.897007465362549
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.9139883518218994
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.834001064300537
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.934995651245117
```

2) screen.blit()

Sum = 14.843550443649292

```
x100 - Elapsed time: 0.2919886112213135
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.8539986610412598
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.914994239807129
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.926569938659668
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.9420039653778076
x1000 - Elapsed time: 2.9139950275421143
```